# Facebook like button not listing my friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have the Like button with faces on my site and it gathered 7 likes, of which some were my friends (faces shown) and some were not (faces not shown).

At some point during the past months (can't track all my pages so I don't know exactly), something broke so that the button no longer lists any friends. It just shows "Be the first of your friends to like this." The like count is still 7 but I don't see who they are.

1) I'm absolutely sure I wasn't un-friended by all these people.
2) I'm very sure that the iframe, code etc. was not changed. It just stopped working.
3) Running the link through the linter doesn't help. No errors/warnings are reported by the linter.
4) Increasing iframe height doens't seem to help
5) The same friends whose pictures dissapeared from some pages still show in others (generated from the same php therefore correct), which seems to prove that this is not a privacy issue, besides, how could there be a privacy issue with so many people?

This totally beats me, any ideas? See some links below.

http://www.great-passage.com/?photoId=59

http://www.great-passage.com/?photoId=98

Comment: I've seen this as well. I've logged this as a bug with Facebook. If you see this continuing to happen, subscribe to it at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/223450547797267.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shows 7 likes for me

[image]

What I think is happening. Your logged off of Facebook or logged in as a different user and viewing the webpage. Try toggling logging on and off and refreshing browser cache and see if it changes.

The best way to verify whats going on here is to look behind the scenes.

Open Graph call for URL's

https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.great-passage.com/?photoId=59

```
{
   "http://www.great-passage.com/?photoId=59": {
      "id": "http://www.great-passage.com/?photoId=59",
      "shares": 7
   }
}
```

https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.great-passage.com/?photoId=98

```
{
   "http://www.great-passage.com/?photoId=98": {
      "id": "http://www.great-passage.com/?photoId=98",
      "shares": 23
   }
}
```

Comment: When not logged it says "7 people like this."
When logged, it says "Be the first of your friends to like this.", as if, neither of the likers would be a friend, which is not true.

Comment: maybe it is true. in any case I'll update the answer with a more detailed look at it.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. The graph API gives correct share counts, as well as the FQL query, see below

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20url,%20normalized_url,%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count,%20click_count,%20comments_fbid,%20commentsbox_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url=%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.great-passage.com%2F%3FphotoId%3D98%27&format=XML

The problem remains, that no faces are shown for these likers.

Also noticed: if I myself click on Like, I get "Error" that tells me to run the linter, however, the linter reports no problems.

Comment: hmm, so I assume you passed the url through the object debugger.. `http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=`, it usually updates the urls as well as retrieving

Comment: Yes I did.

Now if you're sitting down, let me give you the good news: it got fixed overnight. I didn't change a thing. Now most of my photos show me faces of the likers, most of which were from among my friends, just as I thought.

Now, me liking a page doesn't yield an error, and the Insights page looks like it should. What can we make of this?

Comment: It does but when it comes to programming, this prospect gives me the creeps

Comment: just takes a lot of research and read books in the Friends of Ed line. the best programming books IMO. Anyways, you can accept my answer. I wont mind :)

Answer (score 0):

when I look at your source code, I see this:

```
<div id="like" class="transparent"><iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=174634935928464&amp;href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.great-passage.com%2F%3FphotoId%3D59&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=100&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;font=arial&amp;height=20" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100px; height:20px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe></div>
```

Do you see
    show_faces=false
I believe it should be
    =true

Comment: ok, what I saw got deleted when I clicked post. anyway, the essential is there, and since it got fixed, I guess it's just because I don't have friends on your page ;)

Comment: thanks but I have two iframes one with show_faces=false and one with show_faces=true

Comment: and by the way, the problem is still with me. For example this page: http://www.great-passage.com/?tag=all&photoId=173   has 10 likers with a mojority of friends I'm sure